# Disable user's console request in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, security

On my website, if you type **angular.version** on the console (using chrome), you get an answer from the server like

```
Object {full: "1.5.3", major: 1, minor: 5, dot: 3, codeName: "diplohaplontic-meiosis"}
```

It might cause security issues. I tried to enter this command on others website built with angularJS, and I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

How to block user's interactions with the console ?

Comment: are you using a minified version of angular?

Comment: you cannot block user interaction with the console; you can't even fix this by minifying your scripts.  on the websites you tried and it didn't work, you were probably not targeting `top` in the console.

Comment: @HFA I'm not. Why should it change something ?

Comment: @Claies Thank for your answer. What do you mean with targeting top in the console ?

Comment: in the console window, you have the clear button, the filter button, then the **context** that the console will be run against.  `top` is the entire browser context, but you could run against a narrower context or against a chrome plugin, for example.

Comment: @Claies Indeed, it displays the angular version of the website when selecting top. Didn't know that!